# How do I check the validation of several forms in a list?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

For a personnal project, I have a view that regroups several froms. For a spacial reason a had to make a list and in that list I added some forms depending on the data in my DB. So my question is : how can I check the validation a those forms that are present in the list.

Here is my view :

```
def confirmation_view(request, id ,*args, **kwargs):
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(pk=id)
    sport = tournament.sport
    rule = Rule.objects.get(tournament=tournament)
    categories = Category.objects.filter(tournament=tournament)
    form_tournament = TournamentCreationForm(request.POST or None, instance=tournament)
    form_sport      = SportEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=sport)
    form_rule       = RuleForm(request.POST or None, instance=rule)

    enum = 1
    tab_form_category = []
    for category in categories:
        form_category = CategoryForm(request.POST or None, instance=category)
        tab_form_category.insert(enum, form_category)
        enum = enum + 1

    if form_tournament.is_valid() and form_sport.is_valid() and form_rule.is_valid():
        return redirect('tournament')
    context = {
        'form_tournament': form_tournament,
        'form_sport': form_sport,
        'form_rule': form_rule,
        'tab_form_category': tab_form_category
    }
    return render(request, 'confirmation.html', context)
```

I speak about "tab_form_category".

I don't have enough experience in Python and Django to deduce the solution by my self.

EDIT:

Here is my Category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    tournament  = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: **`form_category.is_valid()`** is enough.....It will return either **`True`** or **`False`**

Comment: It will be enough even if there is several form in the list ? I have to check if all the form are valide no ?

Comment: You could call the **`is_valid()`** method before adding them into the `tab_form_category` list. Hence you will have valid forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms.py

```
CategorySubForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['description']

TournamentCategoryFormset = forms.inlineformset_factory(Tournament, Category, form=CategorySubForm, min_num=1, extra=0, can_delete=False)
```

View.py

```
def confirmation_view(request, id ,*args, **kwargs):
    tournament = Tournament.objects.get(pk=id)
    sport = tournament.sport
    rule = Rule.objects.get(tournament=tournament)
    form_tournament = TournamentCreationForm(request.POST or None, instance=tournament)
    form_sport      = SportEditForm(request.POST or None, instance=sport)
    form_rule       = RuleForm(request.POST or None, instance=rule)
    category_formset = TournamentCategoryFormset(request.POST or None, instance=tournament)

    if form_tournament.is_valid() and form_sport.is_valid() and form_rule.is_valid() and if category_formset.is_valid() :
        category_formset.save()
        return redirect('tournament')

    context = {
        'form_tournament': form_tournament,
        'form_sport': form_sport,
        'form_rule': form_rule,
        'tab_form_category': tab_form_category
        'categories' : category_formset
    }
    return render(request, 'confirmation.html', context)
```

in your template:

```
{% for category_form in  categories%}
    {{category_form.as_p}} 

{% endfor %}
{{categories.management_form}}
```

Edit:

In your case you need to look at inlineFormset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets
It's designed to work with related form (you will have one subform for each category associated to the tournament).

If you are using a many to many between tournament and category, you need to associate the intermediary table (through)

Comment: Basically, I'm creating a tournament, and a tournament can have several categories. When I'm editing a tournament, I need to be able to edit the categories associated to the tournament. And each category is a form, that why i want to know how to validate each form presents in the tab_form_category. I tried what you've sent and it doesn't work. If I change one category, it changes all of the rest too.

Comment: I find that the method with the table is easier. Just this : 
`for category_form in tab_form_category:
    if category_form.is_valid():
        category_form.save()` doesn't work. If I edit one and save, it will change all of the categories related to the tournament

Comment: the inline formset looks more complex to implement, but you will endup with a more robust and maintainable code. I can help you to do it if you share the data structure of your models.py

Comment: I just edited the answer to stick to your case, but I don't understand your validation part (you dont save form_tournament, form_sport and form_rule)

Comment: My validation part wasn't finished that why it was empty, but of course i'm saving the other forms. I understood the inlineformset part, so it's nice all works good !

Comment: Told you it was easier and pretty :)